# FlyingSaucer setNamespaceAware to false

Tags: java, pdf-generation, flying-saucer

Compiling the PDFRender class which transforms an html to pdf I got "premature end of file":

```
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.*;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import java.io.*;

public class PDFRender
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException
    {

        createPDF("/home/user/test.pdf", Renderer.class.getResource("/resource/print/test.html").getPath());
    }

    public static void createPDF(String url, String pdf)
            throws IOException, DocumentException
    {
        OutputStream os = null;
        try
        {
            os = new FileOutputStream(pdf);
            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
            ResourceLoaderUserAgent callback = new ResourceLoaderUserAgent(renderer.getOutputDevice());
            callback.setSharedContext(renderer.getSharedContext());
            renderer.getSharedContext().setUserAgentCallback(callback);

            Document doc = XMLResource.load(new InputSource(url)).getDocument();

            renderer.setDocument(doc, url);
            renderer.layout();
            renderer.createPDF(os);

            os.close();
            os = null;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
    }

    private static class ResourceLoaderUserAgent extends ITextUserAgent
    {

        public ResourceLoaderUserAgent(ITextOutputDevice outputDevice)
        {
            super(outputDevice);
        }

        protected InputStream resolveAndOpenStream(String uri)
        {
            InputStream is = super.resolveAndOpenStream(uri);
            return is;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to use setNamespaceAware to false with this snippet, however my code doesn't use a DocumentBuilderFactory

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory =     DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(false);
```

How can i do this?